# Can I post image on friend's wall on facebook using UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am able to post an image on friend's wall using the code

```
-(void)PostToBuddyWallWithText:(NSString *)strMessage
{
    NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"100003146964353" forKey:@"from"];    
    [postVariablesDictionary setObject:strMessage forKey:@"message"];
    [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"http://www.xyz.com/graphics/best-friends/best-friends24.gif" forKey:@"picture"];

    AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (objAppDelegate.objFacebook.isSessionValid == YES) 
    {
        [objAppDelegate.objFacebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed/",self.strfacebook_Id] andParams:postVariablesDictionary andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];

        NSLog(@"message: %@",postVariablesDictionary);
        [postVariablesDictionary release];

        UIAlertView *facebookAlter=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Posted successfully on facebook" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
        [facebookAlter show];
        [facebookAlter release]; 
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
    }  else {
            [objAppDelegate FacebookLogin];
    }   
}
```

But i am not able to find the method to post the image that i am having as an UIImage. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

use this to post UIImage

```
[postVariablesDictionary setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];
```

Comment: it's not working for me. Do i need to add anything except that you told.

Comment: There is no error message. Only text is posted on the friend's wall not the image.

Answer (score 0):

Implement GarphAPI ans ASIHTTPRequest and use below code to POST text with image on friends wall...

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/photos?access_token=%@",[FRIEND_ID], fbGraph.accessToken];

    UIImage * pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSData *picData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pic, 1);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"This is Sample Text" forKey:@"message"];
    [newRequest setData:picData forKey:@"data"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:fbGraph.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];
```

This will work as 100% cheers...I am using this right now...And by the way import FBGraph.h and ASIFormDataRequest.h into your implementation file